# Mongodb query not responding

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

My query does not respond because "CreatedDate" is not indexed. I used the "allowDiskUse" parameter but it still does not respond. What can I do?

pymongo versiyon -> 3.11.3

```
from pymongo import MongoClient,DESCENDING,ReadPreference
from datetime import datetime
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb://xxx:yyy@zzz:27017")
mydb = myclient['db_name']
mycol = mydb["col_nane"]
pipe=[{"$match":{"Channel":"XXXX","CreatedDate":{"$gt":datetime(2021, 4, 20, 15, 36, 58)}}}]
mycol.aggregate(pipe,allowDiskUse=True)
```

Comment: May be try to print the result of the query: `pprint.pprint(list(mycol.aggregate(pipe)))`. You will need index on a field if you are querying a large collection, for example with over a million documents (and this is for the query to perform faster).

Comment: @prasad_ The problem is not printing, waiting for an answer from the server for hours and when I do Ctrl + c it gives buffer error.

Comment: How many documents in the collection? What kind of server (RAM, cloud, etc)? Any indexes on the collection?

Comment: Try using `explain` to see the plan